# Stop docker container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose fails with a timeout:

```
 docker-compose stop mycontainer
```

but docker succeeds:

```
 docker stop mycontainer
```

**My questions**

- What is the difference between `docker-compose stop` and `docker stop`?
- Where can I get more detailed information about that problem? (I killed docker-compose after a few minutes)
- How can I solve that problem with docker-compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved that problem by **restarting the host vm**.
Apparently the docker daemon was in trouble.

Nevertheless I still wonder, why `docker-compose stop` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Doc says that `docker stop` sends a `SIGTERM`and then a `SIGKILL` to the running container, while `docker-compose stop` does not mention that. Maybe that is the reason.

Docs:

- Compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/
- Docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/

You might want to check if you can reproduce that signalling with `docker-compose`.

Edit: More on signal-handling in Docker Compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose stop` it stops running containers that are started when you run command `docker-compose start` . it base on `docker-compose` file.

Please take a look content of `docker-compose` file for more details.

Running `docker ps` to see what are containers  running.

`docker stop` actually, `docker stop running_container_id` it stops running container.